# How to create a new column on pyspark under condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following `data.frame` in `spark`

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit

ddf = spark.createDataFrame([[None, 'Michael',2],
                             [30, 'Andy',3],
                             [19, 'Justin',4],
                             [30, 'James Dr No From Russia with Love Bond',6]],
                            schema=['age', 'name','weights'])
ddf.show()
```

In this trivial example I would like to create two columns: One with the `weighted.mean` of the `age` if `age>29` (with name `weighted_age`) and the other the `age^2` if `age<=29` (with the name `age_squared`)

Comment: what do you mean by weighted.mean?

Comment: so in this example the weighted mean of the people with `age>29` would be `(30*3 + 30*6)/(6+3)`

Comment: please see my answer below if it answers your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first find the `weighted.mean` from the whole dataset with `age > 29` and then populate using `withColumn`. This is because `weighted.mean` depends on whole dataset.

`age_squared` can be done row by row as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
weightedMean = ddf.filter(f.col('age')>29).select(f.sum(f.col('age')*f.col('weights'))/f.sum(f.col('weights'))).first()[0]

ddf.withColumn('weighted_age', f.when(f.col('age') > 29, weightedMean))\
    .withColumn('age_squared', f.when(f.col('age') <= 29, f.col('age')*f.col('age')))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+----+--------------------------------------+-------+------------+-----------+
|age |name                                  |weights|weighted_age|age_squared|
+----+--------------------------------------+-------+------------+-----------+
|null|Michael                               |2      |null        |null       |
|30  |Andy                                  |3      |30.0        |null       |
|19  |Justin                                |4      |null        |361        |
|30  |James Dr No From Russia with Love Bond|6      |30.0        |null       |
+----+--------------------------------------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

You can populate other value using `.otherwise` with `when` function instead of populating default `null`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to do this operation in paralel for the two `if` conditions` ?

Comment: so, two columns are created. One is created under the condition `age >29` (first `if` condition), and the other is created under the condition `age <= 29` (second `if` condition)

Comment: I am asking for educational purposes. Because if the dataset is around 10m rows. then it makes sense to split it in two parts, right ?

Comment: dataframes are already distributed and withColumn is working in distributed in nature. you just need to define partitions suitable for you cluster and data thats all.

Comment: how can i do that ? should i maybe post another question ?